# Ubuntu USキーボードによる日本語入力について

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vscode

## 説明

Ubuntu18.04.3LTSにて、入力メソッドにfcitxを使用しております。

現在、以下のように左altキーで入力メソッドオフ、右altキーで入力メソッドオンというふうな設定で日本語入力の切り替えを行っています。

[image]

### 問題

例えばvscodeなどのアプリを使用中、入力メソッド切替のためaltキーを押したとします。
するとカーソルがメニューバーの方に持って行かれてしまい文字入力ができなくなってしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

vscodeのキーコンフィグでの設定を試みましたが、altキー単体についての設定を見つけることが出来ませんでした。

入力切替を左右のaltキーで行いつつ、カーソルをメニューバーに持っていかれるのを回避する方法を教えて下さい。

Comment: fcitx-configtool で「入力メソッドをオンに」と「入力メソッドをオフに」のキー設定に `Ralt` と `Lalt` の両方を指定するとどうなるでしょうか？

Comment: 両方を指定すると、はじめに設定されたキー以外の入力は無視されました。(「入力メソッドをオンに」にRaltを割り当てていたとして、２つめにLaltを設定しても、Laltは無視される)

Comment: こちらの環境は Ubuntu 19.10/fcitx 4.2.9.6/vscode 1.14.1 で、tan さんと同じキー割当ての場合に同じ現象が発生するのですが、Lalt/Ralt を両方指定するとフォーカスをメニューバーに取られることがなくなります(入力メソッドのオン・オフも正常)。

Comment: 私も`fcitx`を使用していて、同様の事象だったので調べてみました。
調べてみると本家の方で対応方法が記載してあったので共有しておきます。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60282880/5316179

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> キー単独での割り当ては難しい気がします。OS含めて他のアプリでのショートカットと重複しないようにする必要があります。

代わりに例えば <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> などのように、コンビネーションで割り当てるのはどうでしょうか？